# Gradlew vs gradle wrapper

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I have different version for command `gradlew --version` and `gradle wrapper --version`, why is that?
[Gradlew vs Gradle Wrapper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Lfhs.png)

Comment: can you try `gradlew --version` and `gradle --version` ? if this resulted in the same output , then you can update gradlew version , by typing `gradle wrapper`

Comment: It is different version, my gradle version is 7.4.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are two different executables. `gradle` is the one installed globally and located in your path. Adding the option wrapper to the gradle command did not change anything for it and you are just seeing the output of `gradle --version`.

`gradlew` is the wrapper version installed in the current folder. This version can be different to the `gradle` one.

A user of my repo did not need to install gradle at all, when I add the wrapper directly to the root folder.
And even if you have a newer version, my project still works with the version I tested it with. So it is quit common the `gradlew` version is different to your `gradle` version.

You can update the gradlew version with the `wrapper` option and you can also use the `gradlew wrapper` command so the wrapper updates itself.

When you are using linux you can check with `which gradle`, `which gradlew` where the exeutables are located (or `where gradle` for a Windows CMD).

More infos can be found in the offcial documentation:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html